# find id of an element which is found via class name using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<td id="port13">
  <div class="rj45 top up">
    <div class="decorator">
      <span class="classDec class0">0</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>

<td id="port17">
  <div class="rj45 top up">
    <div class="decorator">
      <span class="classDec class0">0</span>
    </div>
 </div>
</td>
```

I need ids of the elements found under class "classDec" i.e id - port 13 and id = port 17

Comment: Can you please more descriptive abt your question.

Comment: @priyanka can you please provide proper html DOM

Comment: I got the corresponding web elements using self.browserdriver.find_elements_by_class_name("classDec").

Comment: The element with class `classDec` doesn't have Id. What exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: @AnkurSingh  I tried get_attribute("id") for the element found via find_elements_by_class_name("classDec"), it returns empty string.

Comment: @Guy is there a way i could get td id = port 13 based on class = classDec ?

Comment: Basically, i have a list of table data with different ids having same span class name. SO is there a way i can get those ids using the class name  as common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locate a list of all the `<td>` tags using xpath

```
//td[div//span[contains(@class, 'classDec')]]

#or

//span[contains(@class, 'classDec')]/../..
```

And iterate over the list, extracting the ids using `get_attribute(id)`. Something like

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[div//span[contains(@class, 'classDec')]]")
for element in elements:
    element.get_attribute(id)
```